# 定期支払のIPNについて（試用期間中の0円決済）

Tags: paypal

試用期間中の決済通知について教えてください。

現在、Sandboxで設定している定期支払いでは、試用期間が0円の場合、試用期間中の通知が行われていないように思われます。
(試用期間中が0円でなければ通知されることが確認できています)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPalの定期支払のことについてですね？
試用期間の料金を０円に設定していた場合は、IPNにて０円決済の通知は行われません。

Comment: いつもご解答ありがとうございます！